# How many assists did Johan Cruyff give for his national team?

Tags: football, statistics

Transfermarkt lists Johan Cruyff's assists when playing in clubs with full detail as being 148. [Johan Cruyff career stats](https://www.transfermarkt.com/johan-cruyff/leistungsdaten/spieler/8021).

However, it doesn't list Johan Cruyff's assists for his national team, something that for other players usually are easier to find (national team assists are easier than club assists). But in this case I couldn't find them.

How many assists did Johan Cruyff give for his national team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Twenty two**

In actual fact, transfermarkt does highlight his assists for country.
According to transfermarkt he made [22 assists](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/johan-cruyff/nationalmannschaft/spieler/8021/verein_id/3379/nurEinsatz/2) in 48 appearances for Holland, and scored 33 goals, whilst accumulating 6 yellow cards and 1 red card.